# Min max word problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I solve the following problem.

Problem:

A rectangular warehouse will hold 8000 square feet of floor space and will be separated into two rectangular rooms by an interior wall. The cost of the exterior wall is 120 per linear foot and the cost of the interior wall is 100 per linear foot. Find the dimensions that will minimize the cost of building the warehouse.

This is what I did

$xy=8000$ $y=\frac{8000}{x}$

exterior wall $2(x+y)(120)$

interior wall $(x)(100)$

$C=2(x+y)(120)+100x$

$240(x+y)+100x$

$340x+240(8000)x^{-1}$

$340x+\frac{1920000}{x}$

$c'(x)=340-\frac{1920000}{x^2}$

$\frac{340x^2-1920000}{x^2}$

$340x^2-1920000=0$

$x=75.15$

The minimum cost is approximatly $x=75.15$

Comment: The second last $x\approx 75.15$.

Comment: yeah I see I have to find out how to make the approximate symbol

Comment: I would suggest saying explicitly at the beginning what $x$ and $y$ represent. Also, one should give some sort of reason that the calculation yields the **minimum** cost. Also, at the end you conclude that the minimum cost is $x=\dots$. That's not precisely true, $x$ is not a cost. Anyway the problem asked for the dimensions. I am being picky, but if you know how to solve a problem,  might as well get it absolutely right.

Comment: The approximate symbol is just `\approx`. I was just noticing that the last value was 75.15 (the correct one) while there was a typo in the 2nd last 75.75.

Comment: I would say there is a minimum at x=75.15 b/c first derivative test

Comment: You still need to show that $c'(x)<0$ for $\left\vert x\right\vert <\frac{80}{17}\sqrt{255}\approx 75.147$ and $c'(x)>0$ for $\left\vert x\right\vert >\frac{80}{17}\sqrt{255}$. (Of course since $x>0$ you can restrict these inequalities).  As André Nicolas said: "one should give some sort of reason that the calculation yields the **minimum** cost."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're work looks good, but you need to solve for $y$, too.

And then you need to use your solutions for $x, y$ to compute the total cost using you $C$-equation, to calculate minimum cost.

So you want to find the dimensions of the rectangle: solutions for $x, y$
And with those values, compute the minimum cost: substitute $x$, $y$ into you cost equation to evaluate minimum cost: $c$

---

*Summary from comments (deleted to clean up):*

Try to keep your solution for $x$ as precise as possible, so you can have a precise figure to compute $y$: $x \approx 75.147,$ but $x^* = \frac{80}{17}\sqrt{255}$.

To solve for $y$: use the equation $$y = 8000/x = \dfrac{8000}{\frac{80\sqrt{255}}{17}} = \dfrac{100\cdot 17}{\sqrt{255}}$$

And finally, you need to show that (even though we know that the minimum must occur when $c'(x) = 0$, and need $x>0$, hence only one possible minimum exists, you should still justify that your solution:

$x^*$ indeed gives a minimum: that $c'(x) < 0$ when $0 \lt x \lt x^*$ and $c'(x) > 0$ when $x>x^*$

Comment: I see thanks I will now try to solve for y

Comment: For y I got y=5109.90 unless I made some sort of mistake I plugged x into 340x+1920000/(x)

Comment: Oh I see I now thanks

Comment: As I commented above we still need to show that $c'(x)<0$ for $\left\vert x\right\vert <\frac{80}{17}\sqrt{255}\approx 75.147$ and $c'(x)>0$ for $\left\vert x\right\vert >\frac{80}{17}\sqrt{255}$.